# Using requests for multipart/form data for API

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to use requests for a multipart data submission on SpeechMatics API.

The API is declared like this in curl:

```
curl -F data_file=@my_audio_file.mp3 -F model=en-US "https://api.speechmatics.com/v1.0/user/17518/jobs/?auth_token=<some token>" # transcription
```

Where data file is supposed to be the local path and model is the language as per the documentation here, https://app.speechmatics.com/api-details#getJobs

Using the requests library, my code is as below, but seems to fail to upload the file:

```
import Requests

path = 'https://api.speechmatics.com/v1.0/user/userID/jobs'
token = {'auth_token':<some token>}

data_file = open('F:\\user\\Bern\\Data Files\\audio.flac','rb')
model = 'en-US'

r = requests.post(path,params=token,files={'data_file':data_file,'model':model})
```

I get Reponse 200 but the file seems to fail to upload.

Comment: try `files={'file':data_file,'model':model}`

Comment: tried and didnt work, the curl clearly shows that files has to be tied with the parameter 'data file'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was guided by a post to use both the data and files parameter for the API.

Below is the cut and paste code that I used.

```
post_api = 'https://api.speechmatics.com/v1.0/user/17518/jobs/?auth_token=<some token>'
path = input()
files = [os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.mp3')]

l = []

for file in files:
    with open(file, 'rb') as f: 

        files = {
            'data_file': f 
        }
        data = {'model': 'en-AU'}

        r = requests.post(post_api,data = data,files=files)
        l.append(r)

    f.closed
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
import requests

files = {
    'data_file': open('my_audio_file.mp3', 'rb'),
    'model': 'en-US'
}

requests.get('https://api.speechmatics.com/v1.0/user/17518/jobs/?auth_token=<some token>', files=files)
```